# Makefile doesn't "stack" my output in a .txt file

Tags: ubuntu, makefile

So, I'm trying to create a makefile that runs my program 5x for each of my parameters (that is 6), and for each of these 6 parameters, the makefile creates a new .txt (my output). But for some reason all of my outputs shows only one result.

```
for t in 2 4 8 16 32 64 ; do \
        #n=1 ; while [ $${n} -le 5 ] ; do \
        for n in 'seq 1 5' ; do \
            OMP_NUM_THREADS=$$t ./cowichan_openmp norm >> normOut$$t.txt ; \
        done ; \
    done ;
```

Comment: Well, you're always redirecting the output to the same file in the inner loop (`normOut$$t.txt` doesn't reference `$$n` anywhere).  So all your results for the outer loop (`2 4 8 16 32 64`) will be concatenated into one file `normOut1.txt` etc.  Is that not what you want?  Maybe you could be more clear about what the problem is and what you want to achieve.

Comment: On the face of it, you have `for n in 'seq 1 5' ; do` and the single quotes mean that the loop is executed once and `n` has the value `"seq 1 5"`.  Where's the typo — in the question or the makefile you copied it from? Maybe you should use `$$(seq 1 5)` instead.

Comment: I want that each .txt output shows 5 results. In total there will be 6 .txt, in each of then should be 5 values. But instead only shows 1 value in each of the 6 .txt

Comment: And I said that's because the quotes around `seq 1 5` in the question are wrong.  You can't use apostrophes `'` there; you need back-ticks ```…`…`…``` or `$$(…)` (the double-dollar gets around `make` expanding macros; the shell sees `$(…)`).  Add a line `echo $$t $$n;` before (or after) the OpenMP line (to the recipe copied from the question).  You'll see what I mean.

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLeffler, it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>*Transferring gist of comments into an answer.*</sup>

On the face of it, you have `for n in 'seq 1 5' ; do` and the single quotes mean that the loop is executed once and `n` has the value "`seq 1 5`".
You need back-ticks `` `…` `` or `$$(…)` (the double-dollar gets around `make` expanding macros; the shell sees `$(…)`).  Or even just:

```
for n in 1 2 3 4 5; do \
```

Where's the typo — in the question or the makefile you copied it from?

If you add a line:

```
echo $$t $$n; \
```

before (or after) the OpenMP line (to the recipe copied from the question), you'll see what I mean.